How to Save and Restore WebView State in Android Jetpack Compose?
I was previously saving my WebView state in my Android app by  overriding onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) method inside the Activity class like this:
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    webView.saveState(outState)
}

Now, I am migrating my app to use Jetpack Compose, and I am wondering how I can achieve the same functionality to save and restore the WebView state.

Save and restore the WebView state in Jetpack Compose could be done by using the rememberSaveable state to keep the Bundle and leveraging the AndroidView composable. Below is a complete example showing how to achieve this:
@Composable
fun WebViewScreen(
    startUrl: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val bundle: Bundle = rememberSaveable { bundleOf() }

    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context)
        },
        modifier = modifier,
        onRelease = { webView ->
            webView.saveState(bundle)
        },
        update = { webView ->
            if (bundle.isEmpty) {
                webView.loadUrl(startUrl)
            } else {
                webView.restoreState(bundle)
            }
        }
    )

}

